# Meaning of filter tag in maven-vault-plugin->configuration->embeddeds->embedded?

Tags: java, maven, aem, jcr

I have following plugin configuartion in my pom.xml:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-vault-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        ...
                        <configuration>
                           ...
                            <embeddeds>
                                <embedded>
                                    <groupId>foo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
                                    <filter>true</filter>
                                </embedded>
                    ...
```

I don't understand meaning of this parameter:

```
<filter>true</filter>
```

I noticed that if I turned it to false then corresponds jar was not installed to the jcr(in cq 5.6.1)

**P.S.**

in CQ 5.5 this jar was installed regardless to this parameter.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

We use it to add the embedded item to the filter.xml file.

I've just decompiled the jar: http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/jcr/vault/maven-vault-plugin/0.0.10/maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.jar

What I have found:

```
VaultMojo.class:

   Line 504: creates a workspace filter

Filter.class

   Line 58: creates the filter xml part for the item.
```

If you set it to false or left it out the jar won't install with the package, because it doesn't have an entry in the filter.xml.

I hope this helps. Unfortunately the plugin is not well documented.